# RegEx in perl only counting first instance

Tags: regex, perl, hash, count

I have a `foreach` loop to iterate through my log file. With what I have, it will only accept the first accepted instance of the Regular Expression before moving on to the next line.

I am trying to count every instance of either Warning or Error and save the count to a hash table. As of right now I can only get 1 instance from each line stored.

```
foreach $_(@logs){

    #regex to find instances of Warning/Error
    if($_ =~ /(warning|error)/i){

        #adding count to either Warning/Error
        if($1 eq "Warning" or $1 eq "warning"){
            $faultCodes{"WARNING"} += 1;
        }
        else{
            $faultCodes{"ERROR"} += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6969208/help-understanding-global-flag-in-perl

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You simply check for the presence of `warning` or `error`. If both can occur in `$_`, or if they can occur more than once, you will need to do more.

```
for (@logs) {
   ++$faultCodes{ WARNING } while /warning/gi;
   ++$faultCodes{ ERROR   } while /error/gi;
}
```

or

```
for (@logs) {
   $faultCodes{ WARNING } += () = /warning/gi;
   $faultCodes{ ERROR   } += () = /error/gi;
}
```

In the first snippet, we use `//g` in scalar context to iterate over all the matches, incrementing the counter for each match.

In the second snippet, we use `//g` in list context to get all the matches, then use list-assignment in scalar context to count them.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're missing the "g" (global) modifier - have you tried (g in bold):
if($_ =~ /(warning|error)/**g**i){

Comment: `if (//g)` makes no sense! (Well, if makes sense if you have an unrolled `while (//g)`, but that's not the case here.)

Comment: I didn't mean literally "//g", I mean't "/gi" which I thought was obvious from the code sample - I've updated my answer to reflect this.

Comment: You missed the point. `if($_ =~ /(warning|error)/gi)` makes absolutely no sense.